# WPF slideshow using full screen views as slides

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, user-controls

I've been stuck on this for a while now and simply don't know how to proceed. I need to create a slideshow using full screen views (UserControls) as slides. By this I mean that I want to transition between full screen views by means of a sliding animation.

The basic idea is to position one view off screen and to the side of the currently displayed view and then to simply slide them both accross. This works well with small images and objects with a PRESET size.

The problem that I have found is obtaining the actual size of each view at runtime. I need this value to feed to the DoubleAnimation that is responsible for moving the views. How can I find out the 'ActualSize' of each UserControl/view before they are displayed?

If you have any suggestions, I'd be glad to hear them. Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE >>>

While the third party transition code worked well for most situations, it turns out that the main problem that I was having was due to the WPF `WebBrowser` control.

Apparently, you cannot create a `Visual` for a `VisualBrush` from it because it is basically a wrapper for the WinForms control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go for a project like [transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) to handle the actual transition.

Then you could consider rendering your usercontrol to some Viewboxed Brush and display that full screen. Mark rendle did a project called [Code projector](https://github.com/markrendle/CodeProjector) which he uses to render Visual Studio's code window to an external screen. That technique could be useful for what you are trying.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried the Transitionals dlls and they work quite nicely, but I can't get them to work at all with a 'WebBrowser' control. 'WebBrowser' controls need to be used for some of the views in my project.