# Animation to change user controls

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a simple custom window (XAML below). 
When first loaded, it will add a user control to the grdContainer.Children collection.
User selection/action will cause other user controls to added/removed to the children collection. (one loaded at a time). What I am attempting to do is provide a simple animation as the new control is loaded, something like a 45degree swipe from top left to bottom right.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WinClientFolder"
x:Name="WinClientFolder"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="450" Height="300" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush />
</Window.Background>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" Margin="18,13,0,0" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" Background="#FFCCC523" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="179" Name="FolderTab">
        <Grid Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grdFolderTop" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtClientName" Height="34" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="Auto" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0"><Run Text="Doe, John Family " /><LineBreak /><Run /></TextBlock>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,1,6,2" Margin="0,45,0,0" Background="#FFCCC523" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="FolderBody">
        <Grid Height="Auto" Name="grdContainer" Width="Auto" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a somewhat similar question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307953/wpf-slideshow-using-full-screen-views-as-slides). I can highly recommend this [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) framework. It's simple to use and looks great.